# What languages are needed to display data from Excel sheet to front end of website?

Tags: excel, wordpress, automation

A website I am working on displays daily congregation times in plain HTML text. At the moment, I have to manually update the times. However, there is an Excel document we have which has all the current congregation times for like a whole calendar year with all the dates included. Is there a way to update that text on the website to display the current congregation times based on the current day from that Excel sheet?

I am trying to learn some coding but not sure what languages to focus on to pull this off?

Comment: You can use Excel VBA to write the html file (a new one each time) with the times you want. Say you select 10 rows and the VBA reads them and creates a html file of those times. Fairly simple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of the Excel file, but my first thought is to save the Excel file as CSV. CSV files are just text files, they are easily read with a few lines of PHP code.

Adapted from my own website, this is how to read the CSV file:

```
// check if the file exists
if ( !file_exists( __DIR__ . '/' . $a_file_name ) )
{
    return;
}

// load the CSV file
$row_num = 1;
if ( ( $handle = fopen( __DIR__ . '/' . $a_file_name, "r" ) ) !== false )
{
    while ( ( $row = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, ';' ) ) !== false )
    {
        // skip header row and empty rows
        if ( $row_num == 1 || count( $row ) == 0  )
        {
            $row_num++;
            continue;
        }
        
        // do something with the row
        // ...
    }
    
    // close the file
    fclose( $handle );
}
```

How to find the relevant row depends on the format of the CSV file. You need to find the part of $row that contains the time information and then check, which one to display.

The other question is where to put this code. I assume from your tags that you want this to go on a WordPress page? Do you know how to put it into a mini plugin and reference it in a post or page, e.g. with a custom short code?